# mat-typography CSS class is not working

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2

I'm following t[his guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography) to use fonts with angular material.
the problem is element classes such as:

```
<a href="#" class="mat-button">somthing</a>
```

is working, while mat-typography global class is not:

```
<body class="mat-typography">  
 <app-root></app-root> 
</body>
```

styles.css:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500";
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons";
```

where is the mistake?

Comment: Did you add Roboto fonts as stated in the doc you linked to?

Comment: thank you, I only added the @import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500"; to the styles.css, what else should I do? I didn't find another thing to do on docs!

Comment: Hi @FurqanShakir, did you manage to solve this problem? I also followed the guide and got the same not-working result..

Comment: @luri Farenzena, no not yet, I had to focus on something else. please post an answer if you found a solution.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by not working, but I just realized that my problem was not adding the `mat-` prefix to the classes names when applying them to elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing fonts and icons in your `index` file instead of the global `styles` files, because I've tried using your `@import` approach and it caused styles to stop working.

```
//index.html
<head>
...
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
...
<head>
```

---

**EDIT**

Also, you shouldn't declare the `mat-button` as a class. So, instead of...

```
<a href="#" class="mat-button">somthing</a>
```

...your `a` element must be declared as:

```
<a href="#" mat-button>somthing</a>
```